# RegExp exclude subdomains from matching

Tags: php, sql, regex, perl

I have a below RegExp

`[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=][A-Z0-9]{3,10})`

It matches domain along with its subdomain and parameters are also needed to be provided in an address, however, I want to be able to exclude some subdomains from matching.
I've tried using negative Lookhead in order to achieve this, but without success.

`^((?!(domain|orsubdomain)).)*$`

Texts which should match the pattern:

`nicesite.abc.com/abcs`

`nicesite.com/abcs`

and shouldn't match:

`niceDomain.com/abcs`

`hello.orsubdomain.com/abcs`

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: When you want to exclude `domain`, this means you want to exclude
 `thisdomain.com`,  `domain.org`, and so on?

Comment: That means that I want to exclude below Upper Case, so below domains should does not match and whole regexp should be false.

`ABC.com`

`subdomain.ABC.com`

Comment: In you exemple niceDomain, “nice” is not a subdomain. And .org, .net, .com... do you want to exclude them all?

Comment: I want to make regexp false when the domain e.g. = `niceDomain`, also when any subdomain exists e.g. `subdomain.niceDomain.com`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
\b(?!.*\.?(domain|orsubdomain)\/?.*)(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]
```

It works, at least with your examples!

Comment: I've added also parameters - `(?!.*.?(domain|domain2)/?.*)(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?.)+[A-Z]{2,6}[/?][A-Z0-9]{3,50}`, works like a charm!